# Wrong picture ploted with matplotlib 3d in jupyter lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I want to draw 3D graphics in jupyter lab with matplotlib, but it does not draw correct graphs.

jupyter lab, run in kubernetes container, with python 3.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.linspace(-6 * np.pi,6 * np.pi,1000)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot(x, y, z)
```

[the output is like this:](https://i.loli.net/2019/07/10/5d25ba2208da997816.png)

Can not find the reason currently, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting the plot to look like?

Comment: it should be like [this](https://i.loli.net/2019/07/10/5d25bb636cb7951173.png)

Comment: Are you sure about your output? I have tried your code, and the output is exactly what you want

Comment: Is this run with a fresh kernel and is it the only code in the notebook?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes.

Comment: @AlessandroPeca yes, in one environment it is ok, but in another not, the docker image is same, only the node type is different.

Comment: Is there a difference in the versions in use (python, numpy, matplotlib) between working and non-working environment?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It is running in docker, so there is no difference.